# Can't revoke GPG key on Ubuntu keyserver

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, certificate, gnupg

I am trying to revoke a GPG key on the [Ubuntu keyserver](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com). I have imported the revocation certificate into my GPG keychain and have used `gpg --keyserver http://keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-key 990CB34A4ACE560F344A89C169EA6ECD0331911A` to send the revoked key to the server.

The key ID is `990CB34A4ACE560F344A89C169EA6ECD0331911A` (as mentioned above), and the revocation certificate in ASCII armor format follows:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Comment: This is a revocation certificate
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=D8BO
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I have tried sending the key several times, and when I refresh the keyserver's result page for my key in my Internet browser, there is no indication that the key has been successfully revoked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import the revocation certificate to your gpg keyring first ? You can do it using:

```shell
echo -n "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Comment: This is a revocation certificate
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=D8BO
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" | gpg --import -
```

After you have imported the revocation, you can check the certificates using:

```shell
gpg -k
```

You will get a `[revoked 00/00/0000]` tag in your revoked public key. After this, you need to export the public key again and upload it to the pgp keyserver.

BR